# How can I draw a polygon on Google maps in Flutter and get all POIs inside of it?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

Given a set of points of interests, how can I allow the user of a Flutter app to draw a polygon on Google maps and retrieve all the POIs inside the defined area?

Is there any Google maps API functionality that can help me to achieve this?

I need to implement a functionality similar to the following but on Flutter: https://kb.ihomefinder.com/s/article/draw-on-map-consumer-polygon-search

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: anybody got solution for this??  PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) package for that.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFJyCaScKD4) is a great tutorial for polygons and markers.

Comment: That is static map, mostly, useless and also not maintained anymore

Comment: anybody got a solution for this?? PLEASE HELP!
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter
official plugin doesn't have support for drawing polygon by tapping on map